Type-narrow angular signal in template?
How do you type-narrow angular signals in a template?
@if (isArray(item())) {   // item is a signal 
     // item is an array
     item() // typescript currently thinks this is either array or not
} @else {
   // item is not an array
   item() // typescript currently thinks this is either array or not
}


UPDATE:
In angular 18.2 a new feature was added as @let. (Source)
So the isArray function can be used in the template. The value and its type can be saved and reused in the template. Example code:
@let memoizedValue = value()
@if (isArray(memoizedValue)) {
  memoizedValue is array.
} @else {
  memoizedValue is not an array.
}

Original answer:
This has nothing to do with Angular. Create a function like this:
private readonly isArray = <T>(a: T | T[]): a is T[] => Array.isArray(a);
Typescript will know the type based on the returned value. Also in TS5.5 this feature was improved. It is might enough to use Array.isArray in the template.
Update: (The question was updated, too.)
As you can see on this example there is one problem. Angular and Typescript doesn't know if you have changed the value of item() or it had any side-effects since the last call. If you save the value to a variable, then it knows there cannot be any change.
Example implementation with value changes: computed(() => anySignal() && nonsignal ? [] : '') This might return different data on each call. This is the reason for TypeScript not knowing the type for the second call.

Yes it has, that won't work. It is actually the implementation of isArray I am currently using. I updated my question to make it more clear why that won't work alone. There has to be some sort of assign item() as someVarName

Here is the working example on Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-afv4gw?file=src%2Fmain.ts

That's a valid attempt but it has some shortcommings: If signalValue is falsy, then we never get to the actual typecasting. E.g. x: any[] | boolean = false. Or in your case with string[] | string if I want to typecast an empty string.

I see your point. This is a shortcoming of the if. Write a directive like ngrxLet if you don't want to change your data. Although you can also write a computed to solve this issue: computed(() => ({value: yourSignal()})).

As of angular 18.2 the new @let keyword saves the world. https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/blog/latest-updates-in-angular-18-2-and-18-1/

This has to do with Angular's design choice of using a function to read a signal. For TypeScript, different values returned by different function calls are type checked separately, unlike a single variable. There is an ongoing discussion on whether Angular should implement a type narrowing mechanism for signal reads in templates: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/49161
